# inkscape strange rectangular around each object

Tags: inkscape

I'm creating this image with inkscape and never had this problem before. As you can see, a rectangle appears around each object. I don't understand why. How can I remove them?

[image]

I have tried to do filters -> remove filters ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the bottom tab of the window(besides layer tab), the description still gives the info that some filter is applied on the object (circle; filtered in layer Layer 1). Select the circles and then try filters- remove filters. If this doesn't work, select the circles and try opening the filters- filter editor and deselect any filter that is applied on the object. Hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have layers with blend modes, like Overlay or Multiply? That could cause this effect and Inkscape shows layer blends as filtered in the taskbar.